# Using WORKDAY in a VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the WORKDAY function in a VBA macro that will auto-fill down a column.  I've looked around and tried a few variations, with mixed results, none of which do exactly what I need.

I need the code to determine if a cell (column I) is empty, and if so determine the previous workday based on a date in cell (column H).  The code I have so far is:

```
Dim rng As range

Set rng = range("I3", Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))

For Each cell In rng
'
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        cell.Value = "=WORKDAY(""H3"",-1)"
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: remove all the `"` around `H3`

Comment: This just carries down the H3 value and doesn't adjust for the rows after.

Comment: do you want just the value or the formula.

Comment: The formula, I need the value being put into the I column to be based off of the matching H date.

Comment: `cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=WORKDAY(RC[-1],-1)"`

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, the macro recorder is really good at giving you reference code for this sort of thing. You probably want something like:

```
Dim rng As range

Set rng = range("I3", Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))

rng.cells(1,1).Formula = "=IF(H3="""","""",WORKDAY(H3,-1))"
rng.cells(1,1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J6"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

This will do the same thing as if you'd dragged the formula down (in regular Excel) to all cells in rng

Comment: You can do just `rng.formula = "=IF(H3="""","""",WORKDAY(H3,-1))"` and skip the autofill.

Answer (score 0):

you van change `cell.Value = "=WORKDAY(""H3"",-1)"` to `cell.Formula= "=WORKDAY(""H3"",-1)"`

or use: `cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Range("H3").Value, -1)`

Comment: `=WORKDAY("H3",-1)` is not a proper use of the formula, do not use the quotes around H3, It also does not deal with the need of the row number to change to refer to column H in the same row as column I.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the value but not the formula in the cell, you could instead use:

```
cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Workday(Range("H3"),-1)
```

...and loop through the cells into which you need to place the value.

If you want the formula:

```
cell.Formula = "=WORKDAY(""H3"",-1)"
```

...and again, loop through the cells where you need it.

These are assuming your function works properly on the worksheet as-is.

Comment: `=WORKDAY("H3",-1)` is not a proper use of the formula, do not use the quotes around H3, It also does not deal with the need of the row number to change to refer to column H in the same row as column I.